# How can I move the zoom tools on the map from the top to the bottom-right corner?

Tags: openlayers

I got a classical map with zoom tools on the top-left corner and I want to move'em to the bottom-right corner. The problem is I don't even know if it's possible.

I've done some research but well, in my mind it should be simple if it exists so I don't know why I've found nothing in several days.

Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 0):

The default CSS has .5em top/left setting and a 1.375em button width/height, so a simple move of 2 stacked buttons from from top left to bottom right would be

```
.ol-zoom {
    top: calc(100% - .5em*2 - 1.375em*2);
    left: calc(100% - .5em*2 - 1.375em);
}
```

but some fine tuning will be needed because there is a 1px margin around the buttons and a 2px border radius around the combination

Comment: Thanks for this tip I see where this is. The problem is I cannot manage to overwrite the ol-zoom class already existing.