# Move openlayers zoom tools on event

Tags: css, angular, openlayers, openlayers-6

Trying to reproduce something similar to [Openlayers with sidebar](http://jumpinjackie.github.io/bootstrap-viewer-template/2-column/index.html) where once the sidebar is expanded the `.ol-zoom` `margin-left` is modified to change its position but I can't use jquery in my project, so looks for Vanilla JS or Angular based solution.

I saw that its quiet easy to change position of the openlayers Zoom buttons as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613023/how-can-i-move-the-zoom-tools-on-the-map-from-the-top-to-the-bottom-right-corner/64879096) but I would like to change the position on some event trigger like a (sidebar-toggle button) button click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
const olZoom = document.getElementsByClassName("ol-zoom");
const sideBarElements = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-left");
if(!this.sidebarVisibility) {
  (olZoom[0] as HTMLElement).style.marginLeft = "0px";
  (olZoom[0] as HTMLElement).style.marginTop = "60px";
} else {
  setTimeout(() => {
    (olZoom[0] as HTMLElement).style.marginLeft = ((sideBarElements[0] as HTMLElement).offsetWidth - 10) + 'px';
    (olZoom[0] as HTMLElement).style.marginTop = "0px";
  }, 50);
}
```

major issue what I was facing was that I wasn't casting `Element` to `HTMLElement` in typescript as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147521/ts2339-property-style-does-not-exist-on-type-element) which was blocking me to apply my `margin` style

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can dynamically add css to the application, for example

```
    var css =
        '.menuSeparator {' +
        '    border-bottom: solid 1px black;' +
        '}';

    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    head.appendChild(style);
```